# force a new validation if another related field changed

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to validate two textfields which are related to each other. The first one must be smaller than the second one (e.g. min/max, start date/end date).

So for the coding part I created this

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
          <v-text-field
              v-model="values[0]"
              :rules="firstValidation"
            ></v-text-field>

            <v-text-field
              v-model="values[1]"
              :rules="secondValidation"
            ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      values: [1, 2]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    firstValidation: function () {
      return [value => parseFloat(value) < this.values[1] || "Must be less than second value"]
    },
    secondValidation: function () {
      return [value => parseFloat(value) > this.values[0] || "Must be greater than first value"]
    }
  }
})
```

I will also provide a snippet here

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NZoaew?editors=1010

When I change the value of one field the other one will not revalidate. Steps to reproduce:

- change the value of the first field to 12

the second field has a value of 2 so you will get an error

- change the value of the second field to 22

now the form is valid but the first field still throws the error because it didn't revalidate.

- remove one character from the first field

now this field revalidates and you can submit it. Is there a mechanism to revalidate the other field on changes and vice versa?

I think a possible solution would be to listen to the `@input` event of a field but how would you force the other field to revalidate then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will validate them both but only show an error in the field once the user has typed in that field:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      values: [1, 2],
      firstValidation: [true],
      secondValidation: [true]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    validate: function (index) {
      const valid = (this.values[0] - this.values[1]) < 0
      if (valid) {
        this.firstValidation = [true];
        this.secondValidation = [true];
        return;
      }
      if (index > 0)
        this.secondValidation = ["Must be greater than first value"];
      else
        this.firstValidation = ["Must be less than second value"];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.16/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
          <v-text-field
              v-model="values[0]"
              @input="validate(0)"
              :rules="firstValidation"
            ></v-text-field>
            
            <v-text-field
              v-model="values[1]"
              @input="validate(1)"
              :rules="secondValidation"
            ></v-text-field>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

(I'm not sure why the styles aren't rendering but it uses the same scripts as your codepen)

Comment: thanks. This seems to be a valid approach. Though I was hoping to find a "ready to use" mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

Any reason why your data model is an array? Be mindful of this. From the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

i.e. when `values[1] = parseFloat($event)` is called, it is NOT reactive. I would avoid this if possible, otherwise use [`$set`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set). Then to force validation of the field when another field changes, you will have to watch for the change and then manually call validation.

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-form ref="form"> <!-- Need a reference to the form to validate -->
    <v-app id="inspire">
            <v-text-field
                :value="values[0]"
                :rules="firstValidation"
                @input="$set(values, 0, parseFloat($event))"
              ></v-text-field>

              <v-text-field
                :value="values[1]"
                :rules="secondValidation"
                @input="$set(values, 1, parseFloat($event))"
              ></v-text-field>

            <v-btn @click="submit">Submit</v-btn>
    </v-app>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Code**

Add this to your component

```
methods: {
    submit: function(){
      console.log(this.values);
    },
    validate: function() {
      // manually call validation
      this.$refs.form.validate();
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // watch for change and then validate
    values: 'validate'
  }
```

See updated working [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KjOObB?editors=1010)

Comment: this is a good solution but I think the first answer fits better to my problem because your way will validate the whole form instead of just caring for these two fields :)